# How can I pass a parameters to a Java Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, parameters

My program doesn't work, how can I improve my example?

In this code is mistake. Eclipse say `Cannot instantiate the type Synchro` in line: `Runnable threadTask = new Synchro(param1, param2);`

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        synchronizuj.setEnabled(false);
        String param1 = main_catalog.getText();
        String param2 = copy_catalog.getText();
        Runnable threadTask = new Synchro(param1, param2);
        Thread newThread = new Thread (threadTask);
        newThread.start();
    }
});
```

and class `Synchro` in another file: (this code is ok for Eclipse)

```
public abstract class Synchro implements Runnable { 
    private String argument1;
    private String argument2;

    public void run(String argument1, String argument2) {
        this.argument1 = argument1;
        this.argument2 = argument2;
        sleepThread();
    }
```

Comment: pass it in the constructor.

Comment: `Synchro` is abstract.  Of course you can't instantiate it.

Comment: The easiest way in my example is adding constructor or is other way? Can I make it without abstract class?

Comment: Yes.  Why did you think `Synchro` needed to be `abstract`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing your `Synchro` class should look like this.

```
public class Synchro implements Runnable {
    private String argument1;
    private String argument2;

    // the arguments pass by constructor
    public Synchro(String argument1, String argument2) {
        this.argument1 = argument1;
        this.argument2 = argument2;
    }

    // you have to override run method, when you implement Runnable interface
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way that works in Java8:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        synchronizuj.setEnabled(false);
        final String param1 = main_catalog.getText();
        final String param2 = copy_catalog.getText();
        Thread newThread = new Thread (() -> {
            ...code to be executed in the thread goes here.
               It can refer to param1 and param2,
               but it can not change them...

        });
        newThread.start();
    }
});
```

The argument to `new Thread(...)` is a *lambda expression*---a compact way of defining and instantiating an anonymous inner class that implements a *functional interface*  (Note: `Runnable` has been re-defined in Java8 as a functional interface.)